# Not able to click a link button using selenium gives error element not found exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to click on the **ARCGIS** button on webpage https://gisapr.atco.com/portal/home/signin.html?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fgisapr.atco.com%2Fportal%2Fhome%2F

But getting no element found or timeout errors.

I'm also unable to access inside login form contents but no luck.

Tried:

- Implicit and explicit waits
- Time sleep()
- by all finds..

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks -- Some code would be cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element <kbd>ARCGIS</kbd> is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://gisapr.atco.com/portal/home/signin.html?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fgisapr.atco.com%2Fportal%2Fhome%2F')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#oAuthFrame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn_wide#ago_Name"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://gisapr.atco.com/portal/home/signin.html?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fgisapr.atco.com%2Fportal%2Fhome%2F')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='oAuthFrame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='ago_Name' and text()='ArcGIS']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

- Browser Snapshot:

[image: arcgis]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: I have one doubt, how to find the iframe id or name , like in our case you found id=oAuthFrame.

Comment: @MOHDALTAF Open Google Chrome Dev Tool, locate the element through the inspector and traverse up the DOM and check if the element resides within `<iframe>`or `<frame>`. If so, you need to switch to the frame first.